# Creating my own filter function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, filter, iterable

I need to create my own filter function in python, i.e., it should return the value from an iterable only if running any given function on it returns `True` or, if the function is `None`, if the iterable itself returns `True`. My problem is that I cannot get to work with a function that returns only even numbers.

This is my code:

```
def my_own_filter(func, *iterable):
    l = []
    if func is None:
        for i in iterable:
            if i:
                l.append(i)
    else:
        for i in iterable:
            if func(i):
                l.append(i)
    return(l)


print(my_own_filter(None, 1, 0, -1, (), "hello", 1, 2, 3, 4))
print(my_own_filter(sum, (1, 2, 3), [], [3, 4, 5]))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: what errors are you experiencing? in your example, you're passing `None` for your func which obviously won't return only even numbers...

Comment: @acushner , it is not a python error, it is more of a logical error. I added an example for call where the func is not None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you are trying to pass a function that will return all the arguments that were even?

If that is the case, you can easily do this if you only pass int arguments, not lists, tuples, or strings.

```
def isEven(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(my_own_filter(isEven, 1, 0, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

In order to make this work with all types, you will have to add some additional if statements to the my_own_filter function. Using the [isinstance function](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance), you can determine if you need to use a for loop to cycle through all the objects inside the list or tuple.

Here is what I came up with to make this work with lists and tuples:

```
def my_own_filter(func, *iterable):
    l = []
    if func is None:
        for i in iterable:
            if i:
                l.append(i)
    else:
        for i in iterable:
            if isinstance(i, int) and isEven(i):
                l.append(i)
            elif isinstance(i, list) or isinstance(i, tuple):
                for x in i:
                    if isEven(x):
                        l.append(x)    
    return(l)

def isEven(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score -2):

it would  be better if you provide your code of function that return even

Comment: this should be a comment